# How can I add a button to the top of my TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have the following in my storyboard and would like to add a button at the top of the TableView that allows me to add Members.

[image]

The scenario, a user is presented with the first screen which displays 'User Profile' and 'Members'.  When 'Members' is touched the next screen is displayed that shows a list of Members and at the top is a button that says '< Settings' whcih allows the user to go back one screen.

I am trying to display a 'Add' button at the top when the list of Members is displayed.

Hope that makes sense!!  I was hoping to not have to Embed the TableView in another Nav Controller.

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: Why are you not doing a push to that second view controller (which would give you the navigation bar to add your button to)?

Comment: I am doing a push usng my custom segue that slides the list onto the screen, but how do I add the button to the nav bar?  Do I have to programmatically get the Nav Bar and the add the button?  Or, can I do it in the designer?

Comment: You create a UIBarButtonItem and add it to the controller's self.navigationItem.

Comment: Duh, should have known that one!!!!  Got it, great thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button into the navigation bar, but first, you need to have a navigation bar.

To do this, you need to select your scene in the Storyboard and then go to the the Editor menu and select Embed In:Navigation Controller.

Once this is done, you can drag in a Navigation Item from the panel on the right.

Then you can add that to your class as an IBOutlet and declare an IBAction for it.

Cool?

Also, I think that your storyboard file might not be set up right.

Check out Apple's Simple Drill Down sample file available here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

Cheers.